# Multiple Javascript If statements that should be working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an invoice project and on the parts section, I have a company price and customer price.

The breakdown is as follows:

- if the part price is `1` to `4.99`, it's a flat fee of `14.95`
- if the part price is `5` to `49.99`, it's `4*` the price

The first `if` statement works but the second does not, any ideas?

```
var five = 4.99;
var fifty = 49.99;
var four = 4;
var fourteenninefive = 14.95;

var qty4 = h.find('[name="requestpartquantity[]"]');
var price4 = h.find('[name="requestpartdb[]"]');
var total4 = h.find('[name="requestcustomerpartdb[]"]');

if (price4 < five ) {

  total4.val(qty4.val() * fourteenninefive);

} else if (price4 <= fifty ) {

  total4.val(qty4.val() * price4.val() * four);

} else {

}
```

I tried your suggestion but its still off, see screenshot below:

```
total4.val((+qty4.val()) * (+price4.val()) * four);
```

[image]

If the Part Price is `10` that means the customer total should be `80`

```
10(Price) * 2(quantity) * 4 = 80
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work... what value is `price4` when it fails? Does it execute the `else if` block at all or are you concerned about the calculation being correct?

Comment: are you sure that comparing `price4` to a numeric value is doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: `total4.val(qty4.val() * price4.val() * four);` -> why `price4.val()` used while `price4` directly used in `else if` condition

Comment: provide your code fully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are getting your prices from some `<input>`s with `name` attributes, you should convert them into integers (that's what `+` in my code does). Also, you forget using `.val()` method on `price4`.

```
var five = 4.99;
var fifty = 49.99;
var four = 4;
var fourteenninefive = 14.95;

var qty4 = h.find('[name="requestpartquantity[]"]');
var price4 = h.find('[name="requestpartdb[]"]');
var total4 = h.find('[name="requestcustomerpartdb[]"]');

if (+price4.val() < five ) {

  total4.val(+qty4.val() * fourteenninefive);

} else if (+price4.val() <= fifty ) {

  total4.val((+qty4.val()) * (+price4.val()) * four);

} else {

}
```

More readable alternative is using built-in `parseInt()` function.